# Simple question on partial derivatives

Tags: calculus

A lot of books basically say this on the subject of partial derivatives:

> If $f(x,y)$ is a function, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ means: when $x$ increases by $1$ unit, then $f(x,y)$ changes by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ units.

My question is about that $1$ unit thing. Isn't it supposed to be an increase of a very tiny $\epsilon$ amount that is very near of $0$ instead of being an increase of $1$ unit in the $x$ value?

Comment: I think they are just trying to say that $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x}$ is the slope of the line tangent to the point $(\mathbf{x},f(\mathbf{x}))$ on the graph of $f$ along the direction parallel with the $x$-axis. It is clearly not meant to be a rigorous statement. You are right to think that said tangent line is a better approximation for $f$ the less the change in the $x$-direction.

Comment: You need to fire those books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The derivative is defined to make $f(a,b)+\varepsilon \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)$ a linear approximation to $f(a+\varepsilon,b)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, in that the difference between these two things is sublinear, i.e. in little-$o$ notation,
$$ f(a+\varepsilon,b) = f(a,b)+\varepsilon \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b) + o(\varepsilon) \quad \text{as } \varepsilon \to 0. $$
Rearranging this gives the definition,
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b) = \frac{f(a+\varepsilon,b) - f(a,b)}{\varepsilon} + o(1)  \quad \text{as } \varepsilon \to 0. $$
$1$ is normally considered quite a large number compared to $\varepsilon$<sup>[citation needed]</sup>, so you're right to query this usage; presumably the point they want to get across is that your first estimate of how much $f$ increases when you add one unit of $x$ is to add the partial derivative on, thinking about situations where $f$ has sufficiently low relative curvature and $1$ is a relatively small amount (I add one atom to my mole, I add one unit of currency onto my spending, ...) that this initial approximation is reasonable, rather than literally correct.

Comment: So, I am right thinking about it as the _"smallest increase imaginable"_ of $x$ will give us a change of $\delta f / \delta x$ in the derivative, instead of _"an increase of 1"_ of $x$?

Comment: In the limit, the change in the function is proportional to the change in $x$: a change by a sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ causes a change in the function of $\varepsilon \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. If the change in $x$ is very small, the change in the function is also very small, but if the gradient of $f$ is not zero, the proportion is finite (and given by the derivative).

Comment: So in this case $\delta f / \delta x$ is a **proportion** of change and not **_THE_ value** of change? (Hence this is why you multiply this proportion of change to the $\epsilon$ value).

Comment: Yes: if you instead change $x$ by $2\varepsilon$, the change in $f$ will be $2\varepsilon \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ (approximately), and so on. Think about the case of $f$ a linear function $ax+b$ to start with. Then $f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x) = a\varepsilon$, exactly.

Comment: And the more we are getting far from $\epsilon$ the more this won't be true anymore, right?

Comment: In general, yes. Obviously there are special cases where the function happens to end up near its tangent plane again, but in general, the linear approximation is only locally reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This may be nothing more than normalizing a ratio to have a denominator of one. To illustrate, let‘s try some concrete units. If the position of an object at some point $t$ is measured in meters and time in seconds, then its instantaneous velocity—the derivative of position with respect to time—would be measured in some number of meters per *one* second. This doesn’t mean that if you let the object travel for a second from that instant in time, that it will go exactly the distance that this instantaneous velocity value would suggest.

That said, if instead of looking at the change in $f$ itself we look at the linear approximation to this change that is given by $f$’s partial derivatives, then if we move one unit in the $x_k$ direction, the *approximation’s* value does change by exactly ${\partial f\over \partial x_k}$ units. Of course, the error in this approximation might be quite large at this distance from the starting point.